# Fails to create upon seeding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, seed

An `Article` `has_one` `Title`. Upon seeding a new title I get the error (referring to the 4th line of my seeds code below):

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `create!' for nil:NilClass
```

What is causing this error? It seems to say that `diagram` is nil, but how can that be?

Seeds:

```
articles = Article.all
articles.each do |article|
  content = Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(2)
  article.title.create!( content: content )
end
```

Article model:

```
has_one :title, dependent: :destroy
```

Title model:

```
belongs_to :article
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message says that `article.title` is nil, which is true given that that's what you want to create.

You should use the methods that the association gives you - in this case you want:

```
article.create_title!(content: content)
```

Reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference